# Why I am wrong to concatenate matrix and vector?

Tags: theano, theano.scan

This is my code in theano

```
max_max=200
beReplaced=T.matrix()
toReplace=T.matrix()
timeArray=T.arange(max_max)


def f(v,k,w):
    return T.concatenate([w[:k],v,w[k+1:]],axis=0)

result,_=theano.scan(f,
                     sequences=[toReplace,timeArray],
                     outputs_info=beReplaced)
```

What I am trying to do is replace `beReplaced` with `toReplace` line by line. The way I do it is by `concatenate` the upper part of `w`, `v` and `lower` parter of `w`.

`v`is lines of `toReplace`.

Here is the error report

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/qiansteven/Desktop/NLP/RNN/my.py", line 20, in <module>
    outputs_info=np.zeros((5,5),dtype=np.float64))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/scan_module/scan.py", line 745, in scan
    condition, outputs, updates = scan_utils.get_updates_and_outputs(fn(*args))
  File "/Users/qiansteven/Desktop/NLP/RNN/my.py", line 16, in f
    return T.concatenate([a,b,c],axis=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/tensor/basic.py", line 4225, in concatenate
    return join(axis, *tensor_list)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/op.py", line 611, in __call__
    node = self.make_node(*inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/tensor/basic.py", line 3750, in make_node
    axis, tensors, as_tensor_variable_args, output_maker)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/tensor/basic.py", line 3816, in _make_node_internal
    raise TypeError("Join() can only join tensors with the same "
TypeError: Join() can only join tensors with the same number of dimensions.
```

What's wrong???????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to concatenate `v.dimshuffle('x',0)` and that solves the dim problem.

Answer (score 0):

Put `toReplace` into `non_sequences`, otherwise each timestep will only take a slice of it. Theano will report error when it tries to concatenate a vector with matrix.

```
def f(k,w,v): #NOTE the argument order change
    return T.concatenate([w[:k],v,w[k+1:]],axis=0)

result,_=theano.scan(f,
                     sequences=timeArray,
                     outputs_info=beReplaced,
                     non_sequences=toReplace)
```

Comment: To take slices from to replace is my objective, that can not change. 
And if put `toReplace` into `non_sequence`, the shape of `output` will change, thats invalid.
The solution is to concatenate `v.dimshuffle('x',0)` and that solves the dim problem. 
Thanks all the way.